# Orbit type stratification of a holomorphic symplectic manifold.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

It is well known that every smooth and every complex manifold equipped with a group action by a (compact) Lie group $G$ admits a *stratification by orbit types*.
I would like to know if there is a similar orbit type stratification in every one of the following cases:

1.) *smooth symplectic manifolds;*

2.) *holomorphic symplectic manifolds;*

3.) *Kaehler manifolds;*

Most importantly, I would like to know if the strata are smoothly/holomorphically symplectic resp. Kaehler.
I would appreciate if you can give some references/literature.

Comment: Are your complex manifolds compact?  Are the compact Lie group actions equal to the restriction to a maximal compact of a *holomorphic* action of a complex Lie group?  Is that complex Lie group a complex Lie subgroup of $\textbf{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, is it a compact complex torus, or is it a combination of the two?

Comment: Cohomology of quotients in symplectic and algebraic geometry. 
Mathematical Notes, 31. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1984. i+211 pp. ISBN: 0-691-08370-3 and see also Sjamaar, Reyer
Holomorphic slices, symplectic reduction and multiplicities of representations. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 141 (1995), no. 1, 87–129.

Comment: The symplectic stratification of the symplectic quotient  coincides with its stratification into $G^{\mathbb C}$-orbit types

Comment: The complex manifolds are not necessarily compact. In the complex symplectic case it  can be assumed that the the compact Lie groups act by holomorphic symplectomorphisms on the manifolds. All complex Lie groups can be assumed to be matrix Lie groups.

Comment: I am still trying to understand your terminology.  When you write "holomorphic symplectic", do you mean "manifolds with a complex structure that is compatible with a specified real symplectic structure", e.g., all compact Kaehler manifolds for instance?  Or perhaps you mean, "complex manifolds that admit an everywhere nondegenerate holomorphic (2,0)-form", e.g., all compact hyperKaehler manifolds for instance.

Comment: @Jason Starr: When I refer to "holomorphically symplectic" I mean a complex manifold endowed with a non-degenerate closed (2,0)-form. I do not assume any compactness of the manifold however. I don't see why my holomorphically symplectic manifold should be compact. Thanks.

Comment: There is a good reference Pflaum, Markus J.
Analytic and geometric study of stratified spaces. 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1768.

Comment: @Hassan Jolany: Thank you for the references and your answer. Does this stratification go through in the case of a complex manifold equipped with a non-degenerate closed (2,0)-form? Do  you know if it goes through for Kaehler manifolds?

Comment: @Flavius Aetius Your question depends on the meaning of non-degeneracy of symplectic (2,0)-form: You may find your answer here: Fehér, L. M.; Némethi, A.; Rimányi, R.
Degeneracy of 2-forms and 3-forms. 
Canad. Math. Bull. 48 (2005), no. 4, 547–560.

Comment: You may check for simplest example(I learnt long times ago from someone): $G^\mathbb C≃T^∗G$ ,which is Kähler manifold and the symplectic quotient $G^{\mathbb C}//G$ is a stratified singular Kähler space. The quotient may be identified with the $ \mathbb T^{\mathbb C}/W$, where $\mathbb T^{\mathbb C}$ is the complexification of a maximal torus $\mathbb T$ in $G$ and $W$ is the Weyl group. The dimension of orbits of this stratification varies

Comment: @Hassan Jolany: I do not quite follow the idea of "stratified symplectic spaces" introduced by Sjamaar. He is stratifying the reduced space of some Hamiltonian $G-space$. I am not interested in that. What I ask is much simpler: You start with a symplectic manifold endowed with a symplectic group action $G$. You ask yourself then if you can partition your symplectic manifold into orbit type strata such that the restriction of the symplectic form to each of the strata gives the strata the structure of symplectic manifolds, as well. I am trying to figure that out. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @Flavius Aetius There is a nice survey paper of See Theorem1.3 http://www.numdam.org/article/AMBP_2006__13_2_209_0.pdf . I think you can ask your question of the author of this paper. Ask of Dr.Baohua FU

Comment: I think your question is very important.There is a very important conjecture of Fu-Yau . Conjecture 6.5 https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0111089.pdf. Every birational contraction from a smooth projective symplectic
variety is necessarily strictly semismall. Equivalently, it can always
be symplectically stratified.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will have a look at the references. My impression is that they deal with very special cases. I need a more general answer. So, what is the end result so far? No one in the whole Mathoverflow knows if you can stratify a symplectic manifold equipped with a Lie group $G$-action into symplectic orbit types similar to the way you can stratify a smooth/complex $G$-manifolds. Whom can I ask then? Who could know?

Comment: You may check also https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/98085/WOLBERT-DISSERTATION-2017.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial answer to my own question that I posed 5 days ago. It turns out that at least in the case of a smooth symplectic manifold you can perform an orbit type stratification. Here is why:

Asume $X$ is a symplectic manifold equipped with a symplectic form $\omega$. Assume furthermore that a compact Lie group acts by symplectomorphisms on $X$. Then if we ignore the symplectic form for a while, $X$ is a smooth $G$-manifold. It therefore naturally decomposes in so-called orbit types $X_{(H)}:=\{x\in X: (Stab(x))=(H)\}$, where $H$ is a closed Lie subgroup of $G$ and the brackets $(~~)$denote the conjugacy class. These are in general not connected, but their connected components, $X_{(H)}^{i}$, have the structure of locally closed submanifolds. These connected components are referred to as *orbit type strata* of $X$ and satisfy a bunch of useful conditions, the most important of which is the *frontier condition*. These conditions are irrelevant here, so I will not mention them further.
The smooth manifold $X$ is decomposed in a disjoint union of orbit type strata. 
Interestingly, each orbit type stratum $X_{(H)}^{i}$, coincides with some connected component $X_{H}^{j}$ of the isotropy type $X_{H}:=\{x\in X| Stab(x)=H\}$. Here is where the symplectic picture comes into play. By Lemma 27.1 in the book "*Symplectic techniques in physics*" by Guillemin and Sternberg the tangent space at the every point $x$ in $X_{H}$, $T_xX_H$ is a symplectic subspace of the symplectic tangent space at the point $x$ in all of $X$, $(T_xX, \omega_x)$.
Hence $X_H$ is in fact a symplectic sub-manifold of $X$. Hence each connected component $X_{H}^{j}$ will be a symplectic submanifold. Thus, the orbit types $X_{(H)}^{i}$ will be symplectic submanifolds. The additional conditions, that strata need to satisfy, are topological in nature so I don't believe that the symplectic form $\omega$ will affect them. In light of what I tried to explain in the above, I believe that a smooth symplectic manifold $X$ endowed with a group action by a compact symplectic Lie group, can be stratified by symplectic orbit types.
Moreover, I am quite certain that the above argumentation goes through in the case of a complex symplectic manifold, since in that case we have in advance a complex stratification by holomorphic orbit types. The only thing missing is that the strata admit a closed, non-degenerate $(2, 0)$-form. This however can be demonstrated in a similar fashion as in the book of Guillemin and Sternberg.

Comment: Flavius : Interesting

Comment: Hassan Jolany: I am assuming the orbit type stratification of a smooth/complex G-manifold. This, as mentioned in my original question, always exists. Then in case we have a smooth/holomorphic symplectic form what remains to be done is to show that the orbit type strata are in fact smoothly/holomorphically symplectic. I hope I did not miss something. I would recommend *Symplectic techniques in physics*  by Guillemin and Sternberg.

Comment: I know this book. I had read half of this book 5 years ago. It is nice book and the book written friendly

Comment: Ok, the relevant part is section II, chapter 27 *Group actions and foliations*. The only drawback is that everything is done in the smooth category.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius I think, there is a small error in your argument. The statement "each orbit type stratum $X^i_{(H)}$ coincides with some connected component $X^j_H$ of the isotropy type $H$" does not hold. The orbit type strata are $G$-invariant, while only the normalizer of $H$ acts on the isotropy type submanifold. Moreover, the tangent space to the isotropy type submanifold is not the space of $H$-invariant vector (you still have an additional direction in the orbit direction), see for example Prop. 2.4.6 in Ortega & Ratiu.

Comment: So one usually restricts attention to the inverse image $J^{-1}(\mu)$ of a point under the momentum map and then take the quotient by the stabilizer group $G_\mu$. This quotient turns out to be stratified by symplectic manifolds. This procedure is called singular symplectic reduction.

Comment: Some similar results hold also in the Kähler category. Here especially one should mention the work by Johannes Huebschmann, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207166v5 in relation with quantization or https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0702017v3 for the case of a cotangent bundle reduction.

Comment: @Tobias Diez: The connected components of an orbit type are not $G$-invariant. Take for instance the $S_3$-action on $\mathbb{R}^2$. There are two non trivial orbit types: the origin-the $S_3$-orbit type- and the the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-orbit type. The $Z_2$  orbit types consists of six connected components. They are the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-strata, but none of them is $S_3$-invariant.

Comment: You have misunderstood me: I have never claimed that the tangent space at a point on the isotropy type submanifold is the subspace of $H$-**invariant** vectors. I claim that the tangent space at a point on the isotropy type submanifold is the subspace of $H$-**fixed** vectors.

Comment: Moreover, I am not interested in singular symplectic reduction, since this gives you a quotient space with a natural stratification. I am interested in stratifying a symplectic manifold with a symplectic Lie-group action. I believe my answer above is actually accurate. I don't see immediately any gaps.

Comment: I came up with even a simpler example regarding why the orbit type strata are not $G$-invariant. Take the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Then the real line decomposes in two orbit types: a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-orbit type consisting of the origin only and the principal ${Id}$-orbit type $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$. The principal orbit type consists obviously of two connected components: $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0, +\infty)$, which are the strata of our stratification of $\mathbb{R}$. None of both ${Id}$-strata is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-invariant.

Comment: You are of course right that things get more complicated when you restrict to the connected components. But in many cases the orbit type strata are actually connected (like in your first example, $0$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus0$). Still, for actions of connected non-abelian groups, the orbit type strata are generically bigger then the isotropy strata. The following relation holds $X_H = X_{(H)} \cap X^H$ where $X^H$ is the set of fixed points under $H$.

Comment: In my second example where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is acting on $\mathbb{R}$, there are three *orbit type strata*: one $\mathbb{Z}_2$-stratum-that is the origin ${0}$, and two $id$-strata-the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$. Both ${id}$-strata are not $\mathbb{Z}_2$-invariant. I agree that the $Z_2$-stratum is connected, I disagree that $\mathbb{R}/{0}$ is connected. As for my first example the $Z_2$-orbit type is not $\mathbb{R^2}/0$, it is $\mathbb{R^2}/(\{0\}\cup\mathbb{R}^2_{id})$. It has 6 connected components, which are the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-strata. They are not $S_3$-invariant neither.

Comment: I agree with your claim that $X_H=X_{(H)}\cap X^H$. I also agree that orbit type strata actually **always** are connected. That is the whole point of stratification, isn't it. You want to get a partition of a given topological space in terms of **connected** manifolds. What I disagree with however, is that the orbit types are connected. In fact they are almost never connected. The connected components of the orbit types, which are the strata, always coincide either entirely with some isotropy type contained in the orbit type or with some connected component of some isotropy type.